# quasar capacitor android emulator can reach 192.68.78.48 but not 192.68.78.48:8080

Tags: android, android-emulator, port, capacitor, quasar

quasar capacitor android emulator can reach **192.68.78.48** but not **192.68.78.48:*8080***

I tried to setting the Emulator -> extended Controls -> Proxy to Manual and **192.68.78.48:*8080***

I tried `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080`

I get [image: Webpage in Emulator]